# How do i retrieve the data without subquery or nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The employees who have the same branch are colleagues of each other. You need to write a query that can give you the colleagues of empid x and the list of colleagues should not include the use x himself.

**Example-** If x=4 then result should be Empid 1 and 5.

**Note**-You have to do it using only one query. No nested queries or Subqueries are allowed.

Employee Table

| EmpId | Branch |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DELHI |
| 2 | Mumbai |
| 3 | Mumbai |
| 4 | DELHI |
| 5 | DELHI |
| 6 | JAIPUR |
| 7 | JAIPUR |

Tried this but I have done this using nested query. I am not allowed to do this, I have to do without nested query.

```
select EmpId 
from ( 
  select EmpId  from Employee  
  where EmpId in (select Branch from Employee  where EmpId='4')
) Employee 
where EmpId != '4'
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Only if there is such an `EmpId` in `Employee`.

Comment: Why are you comparing `branch` with `empid` in the sub-select? That makes no sense. Your initial query at least compared the matching columns (with matching data types) although was more complicated than it had to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a JOIN:

```
select b1.empid
from employee b1
  join employee b2 on b1.branch = b2.branch
where b1.empid <> 4
and b2.empid = 4
```

If an employee can occur multiple times in the `branch` table, you would need a `distinct` to get rid of the duplicates.

---

I personally think a query using EXISTS and a sub-query is a better solution. The limitation "no sub-queries" seems a bit non-realistic to me.

Comment: Sorry the table name is Employee and branch is a column ,pls do have look again .

Comment: @Zubair: well then replace the names.